# Linux Port Forward dependant on receiving IP

Tags: linux, networking, router, port-forwarding, iptables

I have a Linux based router with two NIC’s.

Behind Eth1 is a network with 5 devices, device 1 has the IP 30.0.0.1, device 2 has the IP 30.0.0.2 - both are modbus devices with the port 502 open, the subnet is 255.255.0.0

Eth0 has two IP addresses, 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2 (the Eth1 addresses can’t be changed, but Eth0 addresses can be)

I want to add a port forward rule so:
192.168.0.1:502 <-> 30.0.0.1:502
192.168.0.2:502 <-> 30.0.0.2:502

Is this possible?

The reason for doing this is, the unit with 5 devices in is a standard unit so all the internal devices have the same IP’s and they talk to each other.
However multiple units can be connected to a single external display, the display wants to talk to device 1 and 2 in unit 1 and device 1 and 2 unit unit 2, but I can only set the IP address in the display not the port - otherwise I would use 1 IP address on Eth0 port forward two different ports to the two devices.

Thanks in advance!

—Edit—

The ‘unit’ is a metal enclosure.

Inside there the following 5 devices, connected to the router Eth1 (30.0.0.10):

- Device 1: 30.0.0.1
- Device 2: 30.0.0.2
- Device 3: 30.0.0.3
- Device 4: 30.0.0.4
- Device 5: 30.0.0.5 (This is a HMI which displays Devices 1, 2, 3, 4)
  This is all fixed and cannot be changed, it is built as a standard ‘unit’.

The Eth0 port on the router can be changed, and rules added to the router.

We have several of these units connected to a site network, it has a device which needs to connect to Device 1&2 in each unit, but it can only connect via an IP address and defaults to port 502 for modbus.
If the ports could be changed I would be able to use a port forward in the router so the site device could connect to a single IP and multiple ports but this is not possible.

Comment: you state `a network with 5 devices` then you show 2 different device IP's, then state `the unit with 5 devices in is a standard unit so all the internal devices have the same IP’s` ... so there's 5 devices, 2 IP's but the 5 devices have the same IP ... please clarify

Comment: Hi @Bravo I have added an edit and some details above to hopefully make it a little clearer.

Comment: Doesn't sound really complicated. Have you tried `DNAT` rules (and it's not working) or do you have no experience in iptables / nftables? Also, do other `30.0.0.x` (well, apparently `30.0.x.x`) consider `30.0.0.10` a gateway for any destinations (such as `0.0.0.0/0`, or even, just `192.168.0.0/24`)?

Comment: Hi @TomYan really other than the odd port forward using the GUIs I’ve not had any experience with NATs or iptables. Nothing on the 30.0.0.x range needs to reach outside of this network, there will be no other devices on the small network.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution for this, at least it seems to be working, but I am not a network person so this is really a google answer…would be good to know if this is acceptable, over the top, or if there is a better solution?

Going with the original examples, Eth0 has the IP Address 192.168.0.1, a Subnet of 255.255.255.0 and a gateway of 192.168.0.254 (the ‘site’ router)

```
ip address add 192.168.0.2/32 dev eth0 

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 30.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 502 -j SNAT --to 192.168.0.1:502 
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 192.168.0.1 -p tcp --dport 502 -j DNAT --to 30.0.0.1:502 
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 30.0.0.2 -p tcp --dport 502 -j SNAT --to 192.168.0.2:502
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 192.168.0.2 -p tcp --dport 502 -j DNAT --to 30.0.0.2:502
```

Comment: I don't think the `SNAT` rules here are relevant / necessary. If `30.0.0.10` isn't a gateway on the other `30.0.x.x`, then what you need would be SNAT rule(s) that have `--to 30.0.0.10` (no `:502`; matched with `-o eth1`, `-d 192.168.0.x` and `-p tcp --dport 502`). If it's working without the correct rules, it probably means that 30.0.0.10 is a gateway and hence no SNAT rules are needed.

Comment: Thanks @TomYan I will drop the two SNAT rules and give that a try.